# SharePoint 2013: Can’t open root site on my PC

Tags: 2013, site, farm, root

Good Day,
I have SP 2013 farm with web applications and site collections. I can open these sites on my PC.
The web applications have the URL addresses like

```
http://webservername.domainname.com:portnumber/
```

Recently I created new web application with URL

http://webservername:1895/

And I created the alternative access URL for it

http://webservername.domainname.com:1895/

Then I created new site collection for this web application.
I can open the root site on the SharePoint Web server by these addresses:

http://localhost:1895/
or
http://webservername.domainname.com:1895/

But when I try to open the root site on my PC I get the ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. I tried to open it in IE, Chrome, FireFox. The sites from the other web applications I can open without some problems.
I tried to solve the problem like here

http://www.incrediblelab.com/connection-timed-out-error-fixed/

and

http://spmindmelt.focalpointsolutions.co/creating-new-web-application-error-this-page-cant-be-displayed-3/

But it returned no results.

I can’t understand if I made something wrong and would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Check on server. Press win+R (start>run) C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\ETC . Open host file and add that new host

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it didn't help. On my PC I can't open the site by URL: IP-adress:1895 But I can open the sites from another web applications (they were created by my colleague).

Comment: You need to update DNS host name http://sps2013.blogspot.com/2013/09/steps-to-create-dns-entry-record.html?m=1  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/245761/sharepoint-web-application-dns-mapping